# Add class to Django PasswordInput field in forms.py? (Can add the class toTextInput fields with no problem)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am building a user sign up form and am trying to add the bootstrap `.form-control` class to each input. The class is being added to the `TextInput` fields correctly, but not to the `PasswordInput` fields:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import TextInput, PasswordInput

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
        widgets = {'username': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'email': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
```

When I inspect the password fields, they do not have the `.form-control` class. Is applying this class (or any class) to password inputs something that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem in your code but I cannot test it right now.
You could try adding the widget like this to see if it works:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
        widgets = {'username': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                   'email': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

Another option would be to use django-widget-tweaks:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks

With this you can add classes in your template. But you can also add other attributes.
For example:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{{ form.password1|add_class:"form-control" }}
{{ form.password2|add_class:"form-control" }}
```